Communication through Serial Connection
I'm trying to communicate with IKA hardware EUROSTAR 60. I can read data with no problem. But when I try to output a value(adjusting), my code fails and there is no error message whatsoever. The hardware is connected to my computer using a USB cable. The image below shows the specifications for this hardware:

import serial
import time

serial_port = 'COM7'
baud_rate = 9600

def send_command(ser, command):
    try:
        full_command = f'{command} \r\n'
        print(f"Sending command: '{full_command.strip()}'")
        ser.write(full_command.encode())
        time.sleep(0.5)
        response = ser.readline().decode().strip()
        print(f"Response: '{response}'")
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error sending command: {e}")
        return None

def main():
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial(serial_port, baudrate=baud_rate, bytesize=serial.SEVENBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=1)
        time.sleep(2)

        speed_limit = 213
        command = f'OUT_SP_4 {speed_limit}'
        response = send_command(ser, command)
        if response:
            print(f"Speed limit set to {speed_limit} RPM")
        else:
            print("Failed to set speed limit.")

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")

    finally:
        ser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

The code above tries to change the 'set rpm' value on the device to 213. But the response I get is empty and the value on the device stays the same.
Does anyone know how to communicate correctly?

Have you tried communicating with the device with another program, like Putty, for example? Maybe the space between the command and the \r\n is causing an issue??

I took a quick look at the original manual which says something contradictory: "terminated with Blank CR LF (Code: hex 0x20 hex 0x0d hex 0x20 hex 0x0A)". The hex sequence in parentheses contains an additional space between CR and LF. I don't know if this makes any sense. I have no experience with such devices.

I tried adding and removing spacing, but it doesn't work. I also tried using the hex values, but the issue persists. I tried using PuTTY, but the terminal opens, and nothing happens. When I write a code and hit enter, I don't get a response on the terminal.

Instead of the summations you're writing, you need to provide the actual details in plain language. Your interpretations are ambiguous. "But the response I get is empty" - What do you mean by "empty"? The NUL character was read? Or do you really mean nothing was read, aka no response? "I can read data with no problem" - An example please.
